# displaying simple method names of class using reflection in java

Tags: java, methods, reflection

so I have this class

```
class version_1{
    public int add(int n,int m){
            return n+m;
     }
     public int subtract(int n,int m){
            return n-m;
     }
 }
```

And in my main class I am trying to display just the method name using

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("version_1"); 
Method m[]=c.getDeclaredMethods();
for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++){
    System.out.println(m[i].toString());
}
```

the problem is it displays 
public int version_1.add(int,int)
public int version_1.subtract(int,int)
is there any function available which would just display 
add
subtract

Comment: What is stopping you from using `getName()`?

Comment: Next time please do some research (i.e. read the documentation) BEFORE asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the String like this:

```
Car.class.getDeclaredMethods()[0].getName();
```

This is for the case of a single method in your class. If you want to iterate through all the declared methods, you'll have to iterate through the array returned by `Car.class.getDeclaredMethods():`

```
for (Method method : Car.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    String name = method.getName();
}
```

You should use `getDeclaredMethods()` if you want to view all of them, `getMethods()` will return only public methods.

And finally, if you want to see the name of the method, which is executing at the moment, you should use this code:

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName();
```

This will get a stack trace for the current thread and return the name of the method on its top.